# Populate second table in same report to count same values that derived from a CASE in first table

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have my first table in my report in which I retrieve data from my SQL Server database. In this table I create a new column called TYPEOFTRIP which is derived using a CASE expression (I take two columns from database ORIGIN, DESTINATION) based on that two columns I do a CASE and create that column (TYPEOFTRIP) and basically I write (northbound, southbound, local, etc) now in this same report I they asked me for another table which is are overall counts of types of trips.

I currently have 1 dataset for this report, what I figured was to stored that new column in a #temp table and do a count for that (typeoftrip) = 'northbound', 'eastbound', 'southbound' and put that in the 2nd table in report but I cannot get it to work. Can you please guide me.

this is what I have in my dataset

```
declare @d1 as datetime= case when @DataFor='Last24Hrs' then  CONVERT(date,DATEADD(day, -1, dateadd(hour,-2,getdate())),101) when @DataFor= 'SpecificDate' then @FromDate end

declare @d2 as datetime= case when @DataFor='Last24Hrs' then CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateadd(hour,-2,getdate()), 101) + ' 23:59' when @DataFor='SpecificDate' then @ToDate + ' 23:59' end


SELECT 
q.folio,
q.itemcode, 
ltrim(rtrim(convert(varchar,day(q.oactualdepart))+'-'+CAST(q.oactualdepart AS CHAR(3)))) as Date,
convert(date,q.oacualdepart) [date2], 
rtrim(ltrim(q.roueNo)) as Route,
ltrim(rtrim(q.trailer)) [trailer],
rtrim(ltrim(CASE WHEN q.spec ='HM' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END)) as hazmat,
case when q.TollYN='YES' then 'Y' else 'N' end as Toll, 
ltrim(rtrim(q.LoadNumber)) as [File],
ltrim(rtrim(q.opname)) [operator],
rtrim(ltrim(q.tractor)) [tractor],
q.trailertype as [S/C/B],
'' as [Plan],
q.Origin,
convert(char(5), q.oActualDepart, 108) [HrsOut],
CONVERT(char(5),initdate,108) as InRed,
convert(char(5),q.mxCustomsInspDep,108) as OutRed, 
convert(char(5), q.processUS, 108) as CustOut,
q.destination, 
convert(char(5), q.dactualarrival, 108) as HrsIn, 
convert(char(5), q.dactualarrival-q.oactualdepart, 108) as XINGTIME ,
convert(char(5), q.m[enter image description here][1]CInspDep - initDate, 108) as RedTime,
ltrim(rtrim(tblissues.description)) as ISSUE,
q.tractorCarrier,
tc.CarrierName,
q.tractor+'-'+LEFT(tc.carriername,2) as [Unit Carrier],
CASE WHEN tc.CarrierName='ABCD' Then 'DED' ELSE 'FUM' END as [type],
DATEPART (week,q.oactualdepart) AS Week,
LEFT(DATEPART(minute,q.dactualarrival-q.oactualdepart)/60.00 + DATEPART (hour,q.dactualarrival-q.oactualdepart),3) as xbtime,
ff.frecfolio as frecuenciaf,
ft.frectrailer as frecuenciat,
CASE WHEN q.trailer='B' AND q.origin IN ('A','B','C') THEN 'LOCAL' 
     WHEN ff.frecfolio = 1 AND q.destination='YARD' THEN 'YARD'
     WHEN ff.frecfolio = 1 AND q.origin IN ('C','D','E') AND q.destination<>'YARD' THEN 'NORTHBOUND'
     WHEN ff.frecfolio = 1 AND q.destination='E' THEN 'WESTBOUND'
     WHEN ff.frecfolio > 1 AND q.destination IN ('A','B','C') THEN 'EASTBOUND'
     WHEN ff.frecfolio > 1 AND q.destination='X' THEN 'SOUTHBOUND'
     WHEN ff.frecfolio > 1 AND q.origin IN ('D','E','F') AND q.destination='YARD' THEN 'E SOUTHBOUND' 
     WHEN ff.frecfolio > 1 AND q.origin='W' THEN 'E EASTBOUND'
     ELSE ''END  typeoftrip


FROM 
qrydispatchview q
inner join (SELECT folio, COUNT(*) frecfolio FROM qrydispatchview WHERE convert(date,oactualdepart) BETWEEN @d1 and @d2 GROUP BY folio ) ff on ff.folio=q.folio
inner join (SELECT trailer, COUNT(*) frectrailer FROM qrydispatchview WHERE convert(date,oactualdepart) BETWEEN @d1 and @d2 GROUP BY trailer) ft on ft.trailer=q.trailer
left join tblCarriers tc on q.tractorCarrier=tc.id
left join tblupninspections on q.Id=tblupninspections.legid
left join tblissues on q.id_issue=tblissues.id_issue
where deleted <> 1 and  customer='ABC'
and convert(date,q.oactualdepart) between @d1 and @d2 /*and convert(date,getdate())*/ and itemcode in ('A','B','C')
order by 1
```

[image]

Comment: Create a table showing "Overall Trips" grouped by "Overall Trips" with "Totals".

Comment: What I tried was to make a #table and then retrieve this count from #table.typeoftrips but it gives me and error: "Incorrect syntax near #table, incorrect syntax near 'ff', incorrect syntax near "ft"... I put #table before my from

Comment: You don't need a temp table, just use the existing dataset and group it differently.